# How does this @Override for Arrays.sort work in Java?

Tags: java, overriding

```
Arrays.sort(people, (n1, n2) -> (n2[0] == n1[0])?  n1[1] - n2[1] : n2[0] - n1[0]);
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(people,new Comparator<int[]>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] n1, int[] n2){
        return (n2[0] == n1[0])? n1[1] - n2[1]: n2[0] - n1[0];
    }
});
```

Both these perform the same operation.

Input: `[[7,0],[4,4],[7,1],[5,0],[6,1],[5,2]]`

Output: `[[7,0],[7,1],[6,1],[5,0],[5,2],[4,4]]`

I know the code is sorting it in groups but I don't understand how. I was similarly confused about PriorityQueue in Java:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b)-> b - a);
```

This one sorts in decreasing order.

Can someone explain it? Where can I study or read more about these "overrides" if there is any such material?

Comment: Downvotes are supposed to teach you, not scare you. They mean that you have failed to read the [help] and understand how to form a good question. This specific one is not terrible, but it's still unclear if your problem is that you don't understand what the lambda syntax (arrow) means or what the comparison does. Have you read the documentation for `Comparator`?

Comment: No, I'll go through it. It didn't even cross my mind to check the docs. All I was searching for was  Arrays. Sort @Override methods which didn't work. Thanks

Comment: The `@Override` part is merely an annotation that says the method overrides a method in the parent class/interface. What you have here are two implementations of the `Comparator` interface, one using the lambda syntax, the other, an anonymous class. You should read about all of those topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow notation is a lambda function, short-hand for the same Comparator implementation. That's why you see the same results. It is not about `@Override` here, what you're asking for is how a Comparator works really.

A comparator orders 2 objects in the following order:

- negative, sorts descending
- zero, does nothing
- pozitive, sorts ascending

So for the priority queue part, when the comparator sorts 1, 4, 6, 3, it compares the elements of the array and it swaps them if the difference is negative, e.g. it would swap 1 and 4, 4 and 6, etc.

For the first part of the question, you're using this implementation:
`(n2[0] == n1[0])? n1[1] - n2[1]: n2[0] - n1[0]`

For 2-sized integer arrays, you're comparing the arrays as following.

- If the first element of each array are not equal, you're trying to sort in descending order(i.e. bringing a [7, 0] ahead of a [4, 4])
- If the first element of each array is equal, you're trying to sort in 
  ascending order(i.e. bringing [7,0] ahead of [7,1]).

Comment: I wanted to how its working thought. Ill check the docs for some help

Comment: Ok I understand now, but how does the comparator pair these 2 objects does it do it like [0,1][1,2][2,3] assuming the numbers are index. or like [0,1][2,3][4,5] ?

Comment: @SUVAING see my edit, I hope the Comparator is clearer now. You can read more here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-

Comment: @SUVAING regarding your question from the comment, it depends on Arrays.sort implementation. [0,1][1,2][2,3] is called BubbleSort. [0,1][2,3][4,5] could be a variant of BubbleSort, too, but in practice it's usually used a better sorting algorithm.

Comment: @SUVAING here is some info about the Arrays.sort and its implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) method [`compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) says:

> **Returns:**
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

"Less than" and "greater than" refers to the sort order, not the numerical value, so if you want to sort *descending*, then `7` is "less than" `5`.

So, the following shows how to sort ascending and descending:

```java
// Ascending
(a, b) -> a - b

// Decending
(a, b) -> b - a
```

However, you should never use `-` minus operator for this, since it can cause overflow. Use the [`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) method instead, or the equivalent methods on [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-), [`Short`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#compare-short-short-), [`Byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#compare-byte-byte-), [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-), and [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-):

```java
// Ascending
(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b)

// Decending
(a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a)
```

Next part is that your code sorts by 2 fields, first field descending, second field ascending:

```java
(o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1.a != o2.a)
        return Integer.compare(o2.a, o1.a); // sort by a (descending)
    return Integer.compare(o1.b, o2.b); // secondary sort by b (ascending)
}
```

Which in your code is done using a ternary operator:

```java
(o1, o2) -> o1.a != o2.a ? Integer.compare(o2.a, o1.a) : Integer.compare(o1.b, o2.b)
```

Or rather the other way around:

```java
(o1, o2) -> o1.a == o2.a ? Integer.compare(o1.b, o2.b) : Integer.compare(o2.a, o1.a)
```

Comment: You've got ascending and descending reversed in the first snippet

Comment: @user7 DOH!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` annotation just marks when a method from subclass overrides method from superclass. In your second example you are using something called anonymous inner class, you are basically passing an instance of a class, in your example `Comparator` which has an abstract method called `compare`. You are implementing that methods functionality in place, so that you don't have to create a new class which is extending `Comparator` class and so on.

Your first example is basically the same as second, but its syntax is shorter to write and looks cleaner, and easier to read. The second one is called `Lambda expression`.

Answer (score 1):

Above Arrays.sort accept 2 params. The first is the list need to be sorted, the second is the Comparator. The Comparator is the functional interface that have method compare. Since it's the interface, so you need to implement it (@Override means that your implementation is overriding this method).
The method compare allow you to decide the sort strategy (ascending, descending, blabla).

Answer (score 1):

It's a big leap, but you should learn sooner or later about interfaces, anonymous classes and lambda's.

There's a set of tutorials on the oracle website:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. It helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

From the Comparator.compareTo javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

```
So, what you see is expected. If we take two arguments from your input:
[7, 0], [4, 4]
the evaluation would be: 
n2[0] - n1[0] 
4 - 7 = -3 ( a negative integer)
It sees the first argument [7,0] is less than second argument [4,4] hence it is placed before in order.
```